# How do I trim leading and trailing whitespace and replace it with tab(/t) to make it organized from each line of file?

Tags: unix, awk, sed, trim

I am using Sun solaris 5.10. In my shell script, I am spooling sql o/p data to the Unix file, later i am using that file to send mail using mailx.
My problem is while vim or cat the spooled file in unix, the data comes organized as sql o/p. However while redirecting it to mail or copying it in word file to check data comes disorganized. I want my o/p to be in same order as sql o/p.

```
JOB_ID|JOB_NME                 |START_DTE_TIM                 |END_DTE_TIM           |DURATION                      |STATUS
------------|------------------------------|------------------------------|----------------------|------------------------------|------------------------------
           5|J191-JOB1 |18/08/2020 12:37:09 AM        |18/08/2020 12:37:13 AM|4 Seconds                     |SUCCESS
           4|J191-JOB12   |18/08/2020 12:37:09 AM        |                      |                              |FAILED
           1|J190-JOB3   |18/08/2020 12:37:10 AM        |18/08/2020 12:37:14 AM|4 Seconds                     |SUCCESS
           2|J190-JOB15             |18/08/2020 12:37:09 AM        |18/08/2020 12:37:15 AM|6 Seconds                     |SUCCESS
```

How can i achieve it using awk, sed or trim to make the file contents orgnaized.

Comment: `be in same order as sql o/p.` Does _order_ of data get changed? Or the _padding_?

Comment: order of data comes same only. I am actually referring the o/p format. for ex: Header seperation, column seperation it moves aside because of irregular trailing space between the column values. But while doing vim or cat it shows perfect for viewing.

Comment: I don't know if the 80 char horizontal limit has been removed from email.  If it hasn't, that would probably explain why this is getting mangled.  HTML's <TABLE> might be able to help you, but I doubt this will work through mail in plain text.

Comment: Look for options to your sql-client to un-prettify the output, maybe `--no-headers`, --fieldSep="|"` and others. to make your code *nix cmd-line friendly (piping stages of output to a final printf("%20s\t%20s\t%2d\n", $1, $2, $3)` sort of thing. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Funny enough, the second line preserved the column sizes. So you can read the second line of file and get the column widths from it, then indent all the other columns using the width.

I saved the file in file named `a.txt` and did:

```
# Execute awk with | as separator
$ awk -F'|' '
   # If first file and line number 2
   FNR==NR&&NR==2{
      # save the lengths of all fields in array named s
      for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) s[i]=length($i)
   }
   # if the second file
   FNR!=NR{
        # for each field
        for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
           # print the field
           # if the first field (i==1) then format the field to the right,
           # otherwise to the left
           # use the variable length %*s specifier to pass the length as parameter
           printf("%" (i==1?"":"-") "*s%s",
                 # then lenght of the field
                 s[i],
                 # remove leftovers tabs and spaces in front and after values
                 gensub(/^[ \t]*([^ \t].*[^ \t])[ \t]*$/, "\\1", "1", $i), 
                 # if its the last field, print a newline, otherwise print a |
                 i!=NF?"|":"\n");
           }
      # pass the file twice
     }' a.txt a.txt
      JOB_ID|JOB_NME                       |START_DTE_TIM                 |END_DTE_TIM           |DURATION                      |STATUS                        
------------|------------------------------|------------------------------|----------------------|------------------------------|------------------------------
           5|J191-JOB1                     |18/08/2020 12:37:09 AM        |18/08/2020 12:37:13 AM|4 Seconds                     |SUCCESS                       
           4|J191-JOB12                    |18/08/2020 12:37:09 AM        |                      |                              |FAILED                        
           1|J190-JOB3                     |18/08/2020 12:37:10 AM        |18/08/2020 12:37:14 AM|4 Seconds                     |SUCCESS                       
           2|J190-JOB15                    |18/08/2020 12:37:09 AM        |18/08/2020 12:37:15 AM|6 Seconds                     |SUCCESS
```

Another try for solaris:

```
awk -F'|' '
FNR==NR&&NR==2{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) s[i]=length($i)
}
FNR!=NR{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
        gsub(/^[ \t]*\([^ \t].*[^ \t]\)[ \t]*$/, "\\1", $i)
        if (i == 1) { fmt = "%*s%s"; }
        else { fmt = "%-*s%s"; }
        printf(fmt, s[i], $i, i!=NF?"|":"\n");
    }
}' a.txt a.txt
```

https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/Bash-2

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk, Thanks for you reply. I am getting awk error while running the above script: #!/bin/ksh

awk -F '|' '
   FNR==NR&&NR==2{
      for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) s[i]=length($i)
   }
   FNR!=NR{
        for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
           printf("%" (i==1?"":"-") "*s%s",
                 s[i],
                 gensub(/^[ \t]*([^ \t].*[^ \t])[ \t]*$/, "\\1", "1", $i),
                 i!=NF?"|":"\n");
           }
     }' a.txt a.txt      Error: awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: I hope this works in linux, but not with sun solaris

Comment: gensub is a GNU extension, replace it with gsub (and gsub differs from gensub)

Comment: [Note: i am using /usr/xpg4/bin/awk as awk -F dont work in solaris] and i am getting error /usr/xpg4/bin/awk: line 18 (NR=9): variable "" cannot be used as a function

Comment: I guess that would be at `(i==1?"":"-")`. Something like `if (i==1) { fmt="%*s%s"; } else { fmt="%-*s%s"; }; printf(fmt, the rest)` could be safer.

Comment: [getting error: /usr/xpg4/bin/awk: line 23 (NR=9):wrong number of arguments to function ""] changed my code as below. for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
           if (i==1) {
              fmt="%*s%s";
              }
           else {
              fmt="%-*s%s";
           };
           printf(fmt,
                 s[i],
                 # remove leftovers tabs and spaces in front and after values
                 gsub(/^[ \t]*([^ \t].*[^ \t])[ \t]*$/, "\\1", "1",$i),
                 # if its the last field, print a newline, otherwise print a |
                 i!=NF?"|":"\n");
           }